# Why are vendors offering (much) less gold for items than expected?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As the title says, I've noticed that vendors seem to be willing to buy my items for a lot less than the "value" listed outside of the vendor UI. Examples:

- Potion of Lasting Potency is 311 gold in my "items" view, but Lucan Valerius will only pay 126 gold for it
- Similarly for my Axe of Whiterun: 201 gold in "items," only 81 gold at the vendor
- 500 gold for Scroll of Bane of the Undead in "items," 203 gold at the vendor

and so on. What's the deal here?

Comment: Basic economics - they need to be able to buy it at a price which allows them to resell at a profit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value in your inventory is the worth of the item. Vendors will give you a percentage of that value based on your speechcraft skill and other factors. Likewise they will sell it for a multiple of that value.

Specifically the price is:

Sell price = [ value of item ] / [ 3.3 - (1.3 * [speech skill]/100) ] * [(1 + Haggling %) * (1 + Allure %) * (1 + Fortify Barter from potion) * (1 + the sum of Fortify Barter from equipment + Fortify Barter from Blessing of Zenithar)

From the [UESP Wiki.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speech#Prices)

Comment: My speech is currently 20 (my character is level 13). To get better prices, level up my speechcraft?

Comment: Leveling up speech and getting a few perks will help. :]

Comment: Yeah, just buy and sell items and it will go up over time. Or pray for a blessing from Zenithar or wear items that boost your speechcraft or spell percentage. Oh, and you can give coins to beggars for the gift of charity boost.

Comment: Ah yes, I am already wearing a Necklace of Minor Haggling (12% better prices). The math adds up. Thanks!